# Executes Code even if it returns false

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript Code which adds or removes classes to input-fields. At the end of the Function there is the an if which returns false and gives an error message if an error class has been added:

```
$('#formular_presse').submit(function () {

if (!$("input[name='t_name']").val())
{
    $("input[name='t_name']").addClass ("error");
}
else
{
    $("input[name='t_name']").removeClass ("error");
}


    .........



    if ($(".error").length)
{
    alert (errormessage);
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
});
```

//PHP

```
<form action="index.php?action=add" id="formular_presse" method="POST" name="formular_presse">


//FORM
<tr>
      <td align="left"><br>
        <input class="sendform" type="submit" value="'.$language->GetString("26").'"/>
      </td>
      <td><br>
            <input class="resetbtn" type="button" onclick=\'if (confirm("'.$language->GetString("33").'?")){resetformpresse()};\' value="'.$language->GetString("27").'">
      </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>     
<script> 
    //PHP Variable -> Javascript Variable für scripts.js
        var errormessage = "'.$language->GetString("31").'"
    </script></div>
</div>';
```

When the Submit Button is pressed, I can see for a second that the input-fields get colored red, which means some error classes have been added. But somehow it returns true anyway because it goes back and executes an insert which it shouldn't do.

Comment: Use __`e.preventDefault()`__

Comment: ``if input has a length value``? Inputs have a default of ``" "`` anyway, so even if it was 0, it would still count as a value, meaning the ``if`` would equate to true, and the statement returning false. Try ``if ($(".error").length <= 0)``.

Comment: @Josh Corwe But it adds the error class to the input fields which is correct. The fields get colored red so the class has been added, thus it should return false right? It worked perfectly a few moments ago...

Comment: I could see some error in `onclick`

Comment: just before the last `if`, put an `alert($(".error").length);` so you can clearly see what's going on, and also would be able to see where red coloring is actually happening

Comment: @Josh Corwe - this is not true. the code looks fine, so may be the error is where your "........" are?

Comment: @OliverAemmer Please check the whole code in ellipsis. I think `return` with positive value is located there, so your error check is unreachable.